# Wi-Fi interface missing

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, airport

I have a Macbook Pro from 2011 currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10. Before i upgraded to Yosemite, i was experiencing a common wifi issue that was that the wifi disconnected from the internet and it couldn't be turn on or off; sometimes, when i turned on the mac, a "No hardware installed" message showed. 
I replaced the wifi card but the problem persisted and now that i upgraded the OS, the configuration didn't recognise any hardware and no Wi-Fi interface is shown on Network Preferences. 
I know there is a file `Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/NetworkInteraces.plist` that contains these interfaces information.

Is there anyway that i can configure this file to add the wifi card? or is there something else that i can do? knowing that replacing the wifi card didn't solve the problem and that it may be a software issue?

Thanks

Comment: does the terminal "airport on" do anything?

Comment: There is no such file on my 10.9.5 NetworkInteraces.plist

Comment: the "airport on" command displays something like the man of the "airport" command

Comment: sorry, try this to turn the wifi on "networksetup -setairportpower en0 on"

Comment: It shows "you cannot set wifi power because all airport network services are disabled"

Comment: OK, that was for the WiFi, how about the airport card "networksetup -setairportpower airport on" and you do have at least one of the networks set up in networks preferences?

Comment: It shows the same message: "you cannot set wifi power because all airport network services are disabled"

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that Wi-Fi service is disabled in your system, check by:

```
sudo networksetup -listallnetworkservices
```

If you see an asterisk (*) next to your WiFi, that means the service is disabled. Enable it by:

```
networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled WiFi on
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
```

Same for any other network services which are disabled. See also this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/249796/22781) and this [post](https://superuser.com/a/447112/87805).

Then restart your system to start these services at startup.