# Mac wifi network is spinning and won't prompt for password

Tags: network, wifi, password

I want to connect to a password-protected wifi network at a co-working space.

I chose the network and typed in a password but mistyped it. Understandably, it didn't connect. But I figured I'd be able to click the network name and try again, typing the password correctly this time.

Unfortunately, whenever I click the network name now, its icon just spins, and I'm never prompted for the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal, running this command worked for me:

`networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex en0 PrivateWifiNetworkName 0 wpa2 samplePassword`

such as:

`networksetup -addpreferredwirelessnetworkatindex en0 ETHDenver 0 wpa2 kh43kj4h53`

See also [Command Line (CLI) Command for disconnecting wifi from current network](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/327395/53510)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip terminal, you can go to System Preferences > Network > Wi-Fi > Advanced; look for the SSID– the name of the network you just joined –on the list, select it, and delete it pressing the minus sign down on the left.

[image: Network Preferences macOS Monterey - SSID list]
Alternatively, you can get to the relevant system preference faster if you click on the Wi-Fi icon and then click on "Network Preferences" at the end of the modal menu displayed.

[image: Network Modal Menu]