# How can I fully disable WiFi on macOS?

Tags: macos, wifi

I am aware of how to disable wifi such as this: [Command Line (CLI) Command for disconnecting wifi from current network](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327395/command-line-cli-command-for-disconnecting-wifi-from-current-network)

Is there a more permanent way of disabling wifi removing the module (`modprobe` in linux)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this "more permanent" way? Are you trying to prevent something from turning it on again? Presumably you don't want Wifi on because of .... something?

Comment: This needs more details to explain why the answers in the linked question are not applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `System Settings > Wi-Fi` and set the Wi-Fi switch to off.

Comment: ok thanks. I am looking for a lower level solution, perhaps something with kext

Comment: @CarriMegrabyan - for us to be able to help you need to explain why you need that and why these answers don't work for you

Comment: @CarriMegrabyan A "kext" (which would not help you) is still as software solution. Perhaps wire cutters is the low level solution you need? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it from the CLI with the `networksetup` command shown below:

```
sudo networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Wi-Fi off
```

This is equivalent to toggling the switch in the GUI to enable/disable wi-Fi.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am already aware of these. I am looking for a lower level solution, perhaps with kext

Comment: This is probably something you should include in your question.  What do you envision this “lower level” solution looking like?  To be candid, this sounds like an XY Problem